# Location of close brace in empty private constructor

Tags: java, coding-style, sonarqube

I've formatted my empty private constructor for utility class as follows:

```
private DateUtils() {}
```

This triggered Sonarqube violation of `squid:RightCurlyBraceStartLineCheck` saying that

> A close curly brace should be located at the beginning of a line

I do not entirely agree, as I just followed the convention from the most well-known utility class [`java.lang.Math`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Math.java?av=f#110):

```
private Math() {}
```

Should I treat it as false-positive and bring Sonarqube team attention to this issue or Java sources violate the good practices and I should rather put this brace to new line?

```
private DateUtils() {
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with Sonarqube either.  I'd just ignore it, I really don't care for style checkers that try to substitute for an experienced programmer.  It's a waste of time and money.

Comment: For an empty body I think your style is preferable (easier to read).

Comment: If you disagree with the tool, why use it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch just one false-positive in the tool that contains thousands of (sometimes very useful) rules is something normal, I hope Sonarqube team will fix it.

Comment: @MichalKordas Or you could disable that one rule... but you might want to look into why it was added in the first place. You think this is sonar's support forum?

Comment: Which way does your IDE format the code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch according to http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-End-of-User-and-Dev-mailing-lists-td5035626.html this site will be the only support channel for Sonarqube

Comment: @MichalKordas *SonarQube Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

    This is the place where discussions will happen between people contributing to the SonarQube ecosystem
        seasoned users who want to discuss new features **or give feedback on existing ones***.

Comment: @MickMnemonic IntelliJ by default makes it two-line, but I have "Keep when reformatting - Simple methods in one line" option selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a legit justification, I would suppress the warning:

Either using the annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1109")
private DateUtils() {}
```

or the comment:

```
private DateUtils() {}  // NOSONAR
```

Comment: That fixes the original violation, but causes another one `"NOSONAR" marker should not be used to switch-off issues` http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3ANoSonar

Comment: I updated the answer using `@SupressWarning`. That would resolve the issue if you use their java plugin.